# Are points in linearly general position also in uniform position?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Are the points in linearly general position, also in uniform position? More precisely suppose $C \to \mathbb{P}^n$ be a smooth curve and $\Gamma$ be a reduced subscheme of points in $C$. Further, assume that points in $\Gamma$ are in linearly general position.
Does it imply that the points in $\Gamma$ are also in uniform position with respect to any complete linear series in $C$ ?

Comment: What happens if you take the complete linear series $H^0(C,\mathcal{O}(\Gamma))$?

Comment: Not sure.  Of course, if $\Gamma$ is a general hyperplane section then it is also in uniform position with respect to $C$. However, if $\Gamma$ is the union of two general hyperplane sections then I am not sure. Any Idea?

Comment: My point was only that if $C$ is *not* a rational curve and $\Gamma$ has cardinality $d$, then $H^0(C,\mathcal{O}(\Gamma))$ has dimension $n+1$ with $n<d$. It follows that the points of $\Gamma$ are *not* in linear general position with respect to the embedding of $C$ in $\lvert\Gamma\rvert^{*}$ (assuming $\Gamma$ is very ample). In general, I think that the statement you want will imply that $C$ is a rational curve.

Comment: My question is different. In my case, $\Gamma$ is already in a linearly general position with respect to the given embedding. Now my question whether $\Gamma$ is in uniform position or not w.r.t the curve $C$. In other words, whether every subset of $\Gamma$ of fixed length imposes the same number of independent conditions on any linear series of $C$.